# How do I get the type of a generic parameter on IEnumerable<object>?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I created a method to tell me what the Type of the object in an generic IEnumerable is.
It seemed like a straightforward affair but I got unexpected results when I tried passing the value collection from a Dictionary to my method.
I would like to know how to fix the method to return the right result and ideally I would also like an explanation of why I get the results that I get.

```
//sample class (target type to get)
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

//method that extracts the type
public Type GetItemType(IEnumerable<object> collection)
{
    Type collectionType = collection.GetType();
    Type[] genericArguments = collectionType.GetGenericArguments();
    return genericArguments[0];
}

//sample data for test
var folk = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
folk.Add("Joe", new Person() { Name="Joseph Stalin", Age = 43 });
folk.Add("Tony", new Person() { Name="Winston Churchill", Age = 65 });

IEnumerable<Person> people = folk.Values;
Type itemType = GetItemType(people);
```

The itemType is "System.String" and not "Person".
It seems to take the type generic parameters from the actual Dictionary and not the values collection.

Comment: Curious as to why you chose that parameter type. It seems like the method could be as simple as: `public Type GetItemType<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) { return typeof(T); }`

Comment: I don't actually have the generic parameter T.

Comment: @SynBiotik then make it ;) It's what the <T> in GetItemType<T> does. It doesn't have to be also defined at the class level

Comment: I wrote that sample for its simplicity. The use case for this is for a serialization helper. I currently pass the generic parameter T but the code leading up to this is much more verbose. That's what I am trying to change. But more than fix. I'd like to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is actually a subtle one.  What's going on is that the actual runtime type of `folk.Values` is a nested class of `Dictionary`.  Specifically it's `Dictionary<string, Person>.ValueCollection`.  Effectively the generic parameters get moved onto the `ValueCollection` type, and the first one ends up being `string`.

Ideally, all you should really have to do is change the method signature:

```
public Type GetItemType<T>( IEnumerable<T> collection )
{
    return typeof( T );
}
```

To get around this without introducing an actual generic parameter you need to do something like this:

```
public Type GetItemType(IEnumerable<object> collection)
{
    Type collectionType = collection.GetType();
    collectionType.Dump();

    return collectionType.GetInterfaces()
        .Where( iface => iface.IsGenericType )
        .Where( iface => iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( IEnumerable<> ) )
        .Select( iface => iface.GetGenericArguments()[0] ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

In this case we enumerate the interfaces the collection type implements looking for `IEnumerable<>` and then pull off its generic argument.  Beware, this can run into problems if you find a type that implements `IEnumerable<>` multiple times with different generic argument types.

Comment: This will work, but I strongly encourage the use of the much simpler and more efficient approach recommended by [itsme86](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43380875), changing the method to generic and using the type parameter. At least for the scenario shown in the question, where the type is available at compile-time, it's a better way to do it. The above would be required, of course, if for some reason the method can't be made generic or has to deal with variant interfaces (e.g. all you've got is `IEnumerable<object>` when the actual type is `IEnumerable<Person>`)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Indeed, that would be ideal, but that didn't seem to fit the OP's requirements (for whatever reason).  I'll add it as an additional example anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that there's an underlying type behind `IEnumerable<object>`, and that type in your case is `Dictionary<string, Person>.ValueCollection`.

You can see that if you use the debugger and inspect `collectionType`. To get around this, you could turn the collection into a list by adding `.ToList()` when initializing `people`:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = folk.Values.ToList();
```

Now the type behind `IEnumerable<object>` is `List<Person>` and should give you the result you're looking for.

An alternative "fix" is to change your method signature to:

```
public Type GetItemType<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

That will return a `Person` type as well even without turning the Values collection into a list.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid the recommendation to call `ToList()`. Especially if the collection is any significant size, copying the whole collection just to convert the type to something usable seems like too much overhead to me. But it's certainly one way to do it. :)

Comment: Maybe a slightly less risky version of the `ToList()` approach would be to call `Take(0)` first. E.g. `folk.Values.Take(0).ToList()`. Then you get the `List<T>` object without any contents. Doing it that way would allow the OP's original method code (which is ever-so-slightly simpler than the longer reflection in the accepted answer) to work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetItemType` method gets an `IEnumerable<object>`. Is it guaranteed that all the items in the IEnumerable will be of the same type?

If not, you need to return an IEnumerable of types.
If yes, you need only look at the very first one, and return `collection.First().GetType()`

Is this what you were looking for?

Oh, actually, check out @itsme86 comment, that's a cleaner way to do what you want to do

Comment: It's guaranteed that all the items in the IEnumerable are of the same type but getting the first element won't help me of the collection is empty.